# What happens if they don't elect the speaker of the House by the day representatives' terms end?

Tags: united-states, house-of-representatives, speaker

What happens if they don't elect the speaker of the House by the day representatives' terms end? If new representatives are not sworn in (it's the speaker's job, as I understand it), but old ones are out, does it mean the US can theoretically get an "empty" House with no members? Or is it technically an "empty" House already (I'm not sure when their terms end)? For how long can this paralyzed state of the American legislature legally last? Can they go on without an operational legislature indefinitely?

Comment: didn't their terms already end?

Comment: @user253751: The terms of the 117th Congress ended on January 3.  But I think OP is referring to a situation in which the 118th Congress spends their entire two-year term without a Speaker.

Comment: @dan04 oh, I didn't know that. I only remembered that it was some time in the first half of January